# The difference between domain.com/folder and domain.com/folder/

Tags: html, browser, web

I've been told that these both behave different in terms of loading resources on the page

```
http://domain.com/folder
http://domain.com/folder/
```

However I've also noticed that no matter what I do, the browser redirect http://domain.com/folder to http://domain.com/folder/

So I wanted to ask -- what's the major difference between the two? What should I do for my browser to not redirect (or add the end slash)

Comment: `http://domain.com/folder/` is the folder `folder/`, `http://domain.com/folder` is the file `folder` (without an extension) in the root directory.

Comment: @Reeno Hmm I never thought it that way -- how does the browser interpret the file without an extension? I see some websites use /folder structure to display content whereas the bes I could do (for a static website) was /folder/ as I have my subfolders and index.html in every one of them

Comment: In the end, it depends on how the server behaves. Many servers automatically search for the folder `folder/` and serve it, when the file `folder` was requested. You could create a file without an extension but then you'd need to tell the server how to interpret & serve it (interpret as PHP, Ruby etc, serve as HTML, JPG, GIF etc.). If you don't tell the server, he decides what to do (display as text, serve for download...)

Answer (score 1):

They are different URLs. The biggest difference between them is that URLs consisting of relative paths will resolve from `http://example.com/` for one and `http://example.com/folder/` for the other.

> However I've also noticed that no matter what I do, the browser redirect

No, it won't.

Given a path that the HTTP server resolves as a static directory on the file system, the default configuration of most HTTP servers is to send an HTTP redirect to add the `/` on the end.

It is the *server* redirecting, not the browser.

How you change that depends on the server, not the browser.

> What should I do for my browser to not redirect (or add the end slash)

Generally speaking, you shouldn't. That's normal behaviour. (And, as mentioned, it depends on your server.)

If the changing path is causing problems for relative URIs, then use relative URIs with absolute paths in them (i.e. which start with a `/`).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. In this case I should ask (depending on the comment of Reeno to the main question) - is /folder a file whereas /folder/ is a folder?

Comment: Both are URLs. Both will probably give you an HTML document. Everything else is an implementation detail for the server to worry about. (Given static hosting, one will probably map on to a file and the other will probably map on to directory which will cause the server to generate an HTML document containing a list of files in that directory)

Comment: in this case if I have folders for all of my "works" in a portfolio in a structure like /works/client1 (client1 being a folder) /works/client2 etc. should I create the hyperlinks as /works/client1/ or without the slash at the end?

Comment: With the slash, otherwise the browser has to ask for /works/client1, be told that it should get /works/client1/ instead and then have to ask for /works/client1/

Comment: Hmm I see --- in this case, as a final question - how can I change this behavior for a static website? I don't like the slashes at the end, but creating subfolders always cause this as far as I understand from this thread so far.

Comment: I have no idea what server you are using (and I wouldn't do it anyway - people expect there to be either a / or a file extension at the end).

Comment: I have no idea how to configure nginx. I've never used it.